# JAVA JPanel sliding out and sliding in at the same time

Tags: java, animation, jpanel, sliding

I have a problem with moving JPanels.

I have a window 400x600 and a JPanel (with red color) 100x100

```
public class RulettModel {
    private int num;

    public void Slide() {
        num = num + 1;
        if(num > 600) {
            num = -100;
        }
    }

    public int getNum() {
        return num;
    }
}
```

---

```
class RulettListener implements ActionListener{
    Timer tm = new Timer(1, this);

   @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        tm.start();
        int y = 0;

        theModel.Slide();

        theView.setNewLocationOfPiros(theModel.getNum(), y);         
    }
}
```

---

```
void setNewLocationOfJpanel(int x, int y) {
    JPanel1.setLocation(x,y);
 }
```

---

This Code is part of my code which is need here, this works fine my JPanel is sliding out of the window to the right side and when it out of window width its start coming back from -100 so from the left side

The problem I have got:
I want my JPanel to come in from the left side before it completele went out at the right side.

So If half of the Panel already went out then that half should already appear at the left so my panel should be at 2 locations at a time, half here and half there is that possible somehow?

Any other tips appreciated for solve that thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before coding the below, I used Microsoft Paint to make 7 rectangles of different colors, 60 pixels wide and 90 pixels tall.  Where you see `jf.setSize(186,120)` I only got these values by trial and error.  My timerDelay i just guessed would be an appropriate value.  All other values should be obvious as to why.

The key to all of this is that in the TimerActionListener I simply getLocation() of each tiles[i], add 5 to the x co-ordinate, and reset it to -120 when it reaches 300, then setLocation(int, int) again.

```
package SlidingTiles;

import ...;

public class Main 
{
    private static int timerDelay = 100;
    private static Timer t = new Timer(timerDelay, new TimerActionListener());

    private static JFrame jf = new JFrame();
    private static JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    private static String[] colors = { "blue", "brown", "green", "grey", "purple", "red", "yellow" };
    private static JLabel[] tiles = new JLabel[7];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {


        for(int i=0; i<7; ++i)
        {
            tiles[i] = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("tiles/"+colors[i]+".jpg"));
            tiles[i].setBounds(-120+60*i,0,60,90);
            jf.add(tiles[i]);
        }

        jf.add(jp);
        jf.setSize(186,120);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.start();
    }

    public static class TimerActionListener implements ActionListener
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            for(int i=0; i<7; ++i)
            {
                Point p = tiles[i].getLocation();
                int newX = (int) p.getX()+5;
                if(newX == 300)
                    newX = -120;

                tiles[i].setLocation(newX, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need 2 JPanels.  Then I would have

```
public class RulettModel {
    private int num1, num2;

    public void Slide() {
        num1 = num1 + 1;
        if(num1 > 600) {
            num2 = 500-num1;
        }
    }

    public int getNum1() {
        return num1;
    }

    public int getNum2() {
        return num2;
    }
}
```

and have `setNewLocOfJPanel1(int, int)` and `setNewLocOfJPanel2(int, int)` methods

Comment: Nice idea but the problem with that in the future i want the whole line with full of JPanels Red and Black so every JPanel should have a duplicate that would be a mess isnt that?

Comment: hmm, that complicates it a little, but probably not much.
Have a class that extends JLabel with a method int:setNewLoc(boolean wrapToLeft) and a JLabel[] of this class.  On the TimerEvent (or whatever it's called) each JLabel sub-class in the array can calculate it's own new position, and return it.
The calling method can check if the new position is > 600, and if so, tell the next JLabel in the array about it so that it can start wrapping around to the left.
At some point you'll need modulo arraySize arithmetic, but you could make it work that way.

Comment: I tried it in your way it works but the duplicated panels where should i hide? i made them visible false firstly but can i completly remove them from the window somehow?

http://imgur.com/a/9vBp9

best solution should be to set their location ouf of the window at the position where they should be, can I set them out of the window somehow in the editor?

Comment: I get the impression from your original post that you can set any JLabel's position to be negative, or off to the right of the screen.
So you need to extend JLabel with a class that has an instance variable
int position
and then have an array of this sub-class.  You won't need duplicates.  The only two you really care about is the one that is AS FAR RIGHT OFF THE SCREEN as it can be, and the next one which has to wrap around and start coming from the left.
If you have an array of, say, 20 of them, and the 19th is going off the right side, then the 0th must be coming in from the left.

Comment: Its a little bit cloudy yet.If you can give me some example code I am done and take your answer as complete

Comment: Please see my newly posted answer.  Thanks.